# Depenencies for a module implementing com.android.utils.* and com.android.SdkConstants.*

Tags: android, dependencies

I'm trying to start writing custom lint checks for Android.

I've been trying to get some of the libraries that are used in the default lint checks that Android Studio provides. Two of these are: `com.android.utils.*` and `com.android.SdkConstants.*`. However, I'm stuck at getting the proper dependencies of these two for my module.

Would anyone know which dependencies should be added to make these two available?

NOTE: not `import android.utils.*` but `import com.android.utils.*`

Answer (score 0):

Found it through a dedicated search of one of my colleagues: "com.android:common:r16"